# php ssh2_execute hangs occasionally

Tags: php, linux, debian

I have a debian 6 machine running with php 5.3, libssh2 1.4.0-20120215, using php-cli to connect to several remote machines via ssh2.

my script executes some commands on the remote shell (reading contents of files, executing bash scripts etc.)

normally everything works fine within like 7-10 seconds, but from time to time, the script hangs for exactly 10 minutes when calling ssh2_execute.

i also tried phpseclib, which brings exactly the same behaviour. any ideas would be appreciated. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get logs with phpseclib.